# Camera intent won't return to previous Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, save, photo

I know people will complain that this has been asked before. The reason I am posting it is that I cannot see how mine is different, and it is not working. I have spent over 2 days looking at the other posts, but I'm just not seeing it.

Intended behavior:
I want to launch the camera, take a photo, and return to my activity that launched it.

The actual behavior:
The camera launches and allows me to take a photo, but then it only gives me the option to retake photo, cancel photo, and a check mark.
When I press the check mark nothing happens. It's not frozen, but it just won't allow me to say "yes I have taken the photo, return the results."

The only way to get to my previous activity is to press back or cancel. If I press retake photo, it goes back to picture mode and allows me to take another photo.

What could be causing this?

```
public void addPhotoEvent(View v) {
        IMAGEID = ((View) ((View) v.getParent()).getParent()).getId();
        holder = ((LinearLayout) ((View) v.getParent()).getParent());
        updated = false;


        Log.v(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Photo Event Launch");


        File folder=new File(getFilesDir(),"RedMango");
        File file = new File(folder,"photo"+IMAGEID+".PNG");

        if(!file.exists())
        {
            file.mkdir();
        }
        Uri uri= Uri.fromFile(file);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

Log cat

```
12-31 14:44:34.084: V/Page(23779): Photo Event Launch
12-31 14:44:34.084: I/ActivityManager(394): START {act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=com.android.gallery3d/com.android.camera.Camera (has extras) u=0} from pid 23779
12-31 14:44:34.104: V/Page(23779): Saving Notes
12-31 14:44:34.104: V/Database(23779): Database Connection Open
12-31 14:44:34.104: V/Database(23779): Database Closed
12-31 14:44:34.104: V/Page(23779): Saved Notes
12-31 14:44:34.134: V/CameraHolder(23692): open camera 0
12-31 14:44:34.134: I/CameraService(154): Opening camera 0
12-31 14:44:34.134: I/NvOmxCamera(154): HAL_camera_device_open: open camera 0
12-31 14:44:34.174: V/StateManager(23692): startState class com.android.gallery3d.app.PhotoPage
12-31 14:44:34.184: D/OrientationManager(23692): lock orientation to portrait
12-31 14:44:34.194: E/(154): ioctl SetWhiteBalance failed: -1
12-31 14:44:34.194: E/NvOmxCameraSettingsParser(154): Param type 70 not supported
12-31 14:44:34.194: I/NvOmxCamera(154): HAL_camera_device_open: opened camera 0 (0x41010198)
12-31 14:44:34.194: I/AwesomePlayer(154): setDataSource_l('/system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg')
12-31 14:44:34.214: I/AwesomePlayer(154): setDataSource_l('/system/media/audio/ui/VideoRecord.ogg')
12-31 14:44:34.244: V/camera(23692): mSceneMode auto
12-31 14:44:34.254: V/camera(23692): Color effect value =none
12-31 14:44:34.254: V/camera(23692): autoExposure value =center
12-31 14:44:34.254: V/camera(23692): antiBanding value =60hz
12-31 14:44:34.254: D/CameraSettings(23692): Parameters: [antibanding-values=off,auto,50hz,60hz, antibanding=60hz, auto-exposure-lock-supported=true, auto-exposure-lock-values=false,true, auto-exposure-lock=false, auto-whitebalance-lock-supported=true, auto-whitebalance-lock-values=false,true, auto-whitebalance-lock=false, camera-mode=0, effect-values=mono,negative,none,posterize,sepia,aqua,solarize,nv-vivid,nv-emboss, effect=none, exposure-compensation-step=0.1, exposure-compensation=0, focal-length=2.080, focus-distances=0.95,1.9,Infinity, focus-mode-values=fixed, focus-mode=fixed, horizontal-view-angle=72.600, jpeg-quality=100, jpeg-thumbnail-height=240, jpeg-thumbnail-quality=90, jpeg-thumbnail-size-values=0x0,320x240, jpeg-thumbnail-width=320, max-exposure-compensation=20, max-num-detected-faces-hw=0, max-num-focus-areas=0, max-num-metering-areas=0, max-zoom=28, metering-areas=(0,0,0,0,0), min-exposure-compensation=-20, nv-flip-preview-values=off,vertical,horizontal,both, nv-flip-preview=off, nv-flip-still-values=off,vertical,horizontal,both, nv-flip-still=off, picture-format-values=jpeg,jfif,exif, picture-format=jpeg, picture-size-values=320x240,480x480,640x480,800x600,1024x768,1280x720,1280x960, picture-size=1280x720, preferred-preview-size-for-video=720x576, preview-format-values=yuv420p,yuv420sp, preview-format=yuv420sp, preview-fps-range-values=(4000,60000), preview-fps-range=4000,60000, preview-frame-rate-values=5,8,10,15,20,24,25,30, preview-frame-rate=30, preview-size-values=176x144,320x240,352x288,480x480,640x480,704x576,720x408,720x480,720x576,768x432,800x448,960x720,1280x720, preview-size=1280x720, recording-hint-values=false,true, recording-hint=false, rotation-values=0,90,180,270, rotation=0, smooth-zoom-supported=true, vertical-view-angle=72.600, video-frame-format-values=yuv420p, video-frame-format=yuv420p, video-size-values=40x30,176x144,320x240,352x288,640x480,704x576,720x480,720x576,768x432,1280x720, video-size=1280x720, video-snapshot-supported=true, video-stabilization-supported=false, video-stabilization-values=false,true, video-stabilization=false, whitebalance-values=auto,incandescent,fluorescent,daylight, whitebalance=auto, zoom-ratios=100,125,150,175,200,225,250,275,300,325,350,375,400,425,450,475,500,525,550,575,600,625,650,675,700,725,750,775,800, zoom-supported=true, zoom=0]
12-31 14:44:34.254: V/camera(23692): mSceneMode auto
12-31 14:44:34.264: V/camera(23692): Color effect value =none
12-31 14:44:34.264: V/camera(23692): autoExposure value =center
12-31 14:44:34.264: V/camera(23692): antiBanding value =60hz
12-31 14:44:34.264: D/CameraSettings(23692): Parameters: [antibanding-values=off,auto,50hz,60hz, antibanding=60hz, auto-exposure-lock-supported=true, auto-exposure-lock-values=false,true, auto-exposure-lock=false, auto-whitebalance-lock-supported=true, auto-whitebalance-lock-values=false,true, auto-whitebalance-lock=false, camera-mode=0, effect-values=mono,negative,none,posterize,sepia,aqua,solarize,nv-vivid,nv-emboss, effect=none, exposure-compensation-step=0.1, exposure-compensation=0, focal-length=2.080, focus-distances=0.95,1.9,Infinity, focus-mode-values=fixed, focus-mode=fixed, horizontal-view-angle=72.600, jpeg-quality=100, jpeg-thumbnail-height=240, jpeg-thumbnail-quality=90, jpeg-thumbnail-size-values=0x0,320x240, jpeg-thumbnail-width=320, max-exposure-compensation=20, max-num-detected-faces-hw=0, max-num-focus-areas=0, max-num-metering-areas=0, max-zoom=28, metering-areas=(0,0,0,0,0), min-exposure-compensation=-20, nv-flip-preview-values=off,vertical,horizontal,both, nv-flip-preview=off, nv-flip-still-values=off,vertical,horizontal,both, nv-flip-still=off, picture-format-values=jpeg,jfif,exif, picture-format=jpeg, picture-size-values=320x240,480x480,640x480,800x600,1024x768,1280x720,1280x960, picture-size=1280x720, preferred-preview-size-for-video=720x576, preview-format-values=yuv420p,yuv420sp, preview-format=yuv420sp, preview-fps-range-values=(4000,60000), preview-fps-range=4000,60000, preview-frame-rate-values=5,8,10,15,20,24,25,30, preview-frame-rate=30, preview-size-values=176x144,320x240,352x288,480x480,640x480,704x576,720x408,720x480,720x576,768x432,800x448,960x720,1280x720, preview-size=1280x720, recording-hint-values=false,true, recording-hint=false, rotation-values=0,90,180,270, rotation=0, smooth-zoom-supported=true, vertical-view-angle=72.600, video-frame-format-values=yuv420p, video-frame-format=yuv420p, video-size-values=40x30,176x144,320x240,352x288,640x480,704x576,720x480,720x576,768x432,1280x720, video-size=1280x720, video-snapshot-supported=true, video-stabilization-supported=false, video-stabilization-values=false,true, video-stabilization=false, whitebalance-values=auto,incandescent,fluorescent,daylight, whitebalance=auto, zoom-ratios=100,125,150,175,200,225,250,275,300,325,350,375,400,425,450,475,500,525,550,575,600,625,650,675,700,725,750,775,800, zoom-supported=true, zoom=0]
12-31 14:44:34.264: V/camera(23692): startPreview
12-31 14:44:34.284: D/NvOsDebugPrintf(154): NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 1 
12-31 14:44:34.294: D/NvOsDebugPrintf(154): NvMMLiteJPEGEncGetBufferRequirements : BufferSize 1382400
12-31 14:44:34.324: D/(154): Camera fd open as: 141
12-31 14:44:34.534: D/CameraStorage(23692): External storage state=mounted
```

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks right to me.  Does the file you specify ever get created?

Comment: yea it get's created but it just doesn't return anything. what i did was since i knew where the file is i just checked that location and if it exist i load it. It's not the best solution but still by passed the problem

Comment: i really am confused because i created another intent that allows me to go to the gallery and get an image and it returns the Uri of the image the problem with that was that the Uri was weird and you had to get the real Uri. I found a method online that fixed it tho.

Comment: I'm confused, is your problem solved?  I was wondering if maybe you needed the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission set in your manifest.

Comment: it is solved but not because i have managed to get a return value of where the content is stored. i solved it by checking the area i told it to store the content. since i programmed it i know where i saved it so i check on Activity result if a file sexist. I do have the write to storage permission in the manafest